# Salvar imagens no dispositivo sem expirar

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova-plugin

Tenho um aplicativo feito com Intel XDK, rodando em iOS e Android. O intuito é exibir imagens que estão no servidor, e armazená-las no dispositivo para não fazer o download toda vez que ela for exibida.

Então, além de armazenar, precisaria verificar se ela já existe no dispositivo.

É algo similar ao LazyAdapter presente no Java e usado em diversos aplicativos.

Isso é possível?

Comment: confesso que nunca ouvi falar desse XDK, mas como colocou a tag cordova-plugin, pode ser que o [plugin file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file) funcione para voce

Comment: O XDK usa o plugin Cordova, já vem com compilador próprio (na nuvem), entre outras coisas que facilitam o desenvolvimento. Vou baixar esse plugin por ele (também baixa plugins externos) e te dou um retorno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz algo parecido, mas para ionic/angular como uma diretiva, como disse usei o [plugin file](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file).

Vou deixar o codigo mais como modelo de como fiz.

```
angular.module('imagefusion', ['ionic', 'ngCordova.plugins.file'])
.directive('imageFusion', function($compile, $timeout, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        //replace: true,
        //template: '<div></div>',
        //transclude: true,
        scope: {
            config: '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, $image, attrs){
            var debug = true;
            var localPath = 'images/'+scope.config.name;
            var $spinner = null;
            var ghost = angular.element(new Image());

            function changeSource(src){
                ghost.attr('src', src);

                if($spinner){
                    $spinner.remove();
                }
            }

            function displayLoader(){
                $spinner = angular.element($compile('<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>')(scope));
                $image.append($spinner);

                var wrapperSize = {width:$image[0].offsetWidth, height:$image[0].offsetHeight};
                //var spinnerSize = {width:$spinner[0].offsetHeight, height:$spinner[0].offsetHeight};
                var spinnerSize = {width:28, height:28};

                $spinner.css('position', 'absolute');
                $spinner.css('left', ((wrapperSize.width-spinnerSize.width)/2)+'px');
                $spinner.css('top', ((wrapperSize.height-spinnerSize.height)/2)+'px');
            }

            function formatSize(size){
                var s = null;
                if(size){
                    if( typeof size=='number' || (typeof size=='string' && size.indexOf('%')==-1) ){
                        s = size+'px';
                    }else{
                        s = size;
                    }
                }

                return s;
            }

            var size = null;
            if(scope.config.size){
                size = scope.config.size;
            }

            // naturalHeight
            // console.log(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory);
            // file:///data/data/br.com.nibler.doctorphotosolution/
            if(size){
                var w = formatSize(size.width);
                $image.css('width', w);
                $image.css('height', w);
            }

            ghost.on('load', function(event){
                var target = event.target;

                if(!size.height){
                    var height;
                    var image = $image[0];

                    if(attrs.original!==undefined){
                        // (original height / original width) x new width = new height
                        var originalWidth   = ghost[0].naturalWidth;
                        var originalHeight  = ghost[0].naturalHeight;
                        var currentWidth    = image.clientWidth;
                        //var currentHeight     = image.clientHeight;

                        height = (originalHeight/originalWidth)*currentWidth;
                    }else{
                        height = image.clientWidth;
                    }

                    $image.css('height', formatSize(height));
                }
                $image.css('background-image', 'url('+target.src+')');
            });

            $image.on('error', function(){
                if(debug){
                    console.log('Error');
                }
            });


            $image.css('background-position', 'center center');
            $image.css('background-repeat', 'no-repeat');
            $image.css('background-size', 'cover');
            $image.css('display', 'inline-block');

            if(attrs.relative!==undefined)
                $image.css('position', 'relative');

            $timeout(function(){
                displayLoader();
                //console.log(localPath);
                //console.log(cordova.file);
                cordova.file;
                //debugger;

                var storageDir = null;

                if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()){
                    storageDir = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
                }else{
                    storageDir = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory;
                }
                var fullLocalPath = storageDir+localPath;

                if(!scope.config.name || scope.config.url.indexOf('http')==-1){
                    changeSource(scope.config.placeholder);
                }else{
                    $cordovaFile.checkFile(storageDir, localPath).then(
                        function(success){
                            changeSource(fullLocalPath);
                            if(debug){
                                console.log('['+scope.config.name+'] Fetched from Disk');
                            }
                        },
                        function(err){
                            if(debug){
                                console.log('['+scope.config.name+'] Not exists, downloading....');
                            }

                            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(scope.config.url, fullLocalPath).then(
                                function(resp){
                                    changeSource(fullLocalPath);
                                    if(debug){
                                        console.log('['+scope.config.name+'] Downloaded');
                                    }
                                },
                                function(err){
                                    if(debug){
                                        console.log('['+scope.config.name+'] Download error');
                                        console.log(err);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }

                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Ajudou bastante, valeu!